# How do you make an even border around an element?

Tags: css, image, border, styling

Let's say you have a div wrapping an image. How would you style the div so that it creates a border of even width on all four sides of the image?

Comment: What do you mean by perfect border...?

Comment: I mean even width on all sides, sorry i'll clarify that

Comment: Well honestly, you could set the div to the width of the image...or `div img{border...}`. PS: I think he means that he wants to set a border to the div that looks as if it was set to the image...or something like that...

Comment: It doesn't have to be a div... anything to get a border around an image.

Comment: somethign like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/RyEvY/2/

Comment: @Justin: Any reason why you can't add the border to the image itself?

Comment: no not really, I just don't know the CSS for that...

Comment: the easiest and probably best way is to just put a border to the img `border: 1px solid black;` or something similar

Comment: `img{ border:1px solid black }` where `1px` is the width, `solid` is the style, and `black` is the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the `div` doesn't have to be there, you might as well just give the `img` an actual border and be done with it. Specifying one width value creates an equally-thick border around all sides.

   ```
   img {
       border: 3px solid blue;
   }
   ```

   [jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/m6tw6)
2. Otherwise, if you need to use a `div` as a border for whatever reason, make it an inline block, and make the `img` a block. Then either give the `div` padding or give the `img` margins.

   ```
   div {
       display: inline-block;
       background-color: blue;
       padding: 3px;
   }

   img {
       display: block;
   }
   ```

   [jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vzdLx)

Comment: well, the image and the div wrapping it are generated dynamically, so I think this styling of the div is easier in this case...

Comment: This is correct. Just wanted to point out that inline-block on a block level element makes IE unhappy though.